# How to find missing records from two tables in one query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `items` and `items_archive` which are both missing information due to a faulty stored procedure.

I have a table `items_restored` that I restored from text backups that contains many items that are not in `items` or `items_archive` and I need to end up inserting what `items_restored` has into `items_archive`.

I am able to find a one off comparison pretty easily, doing

```
SELECT ir.id, i_a.id
FROM items_restord as ir
LEFT JOIN items_archive as i_a ON ir.id = i_a.id
WHERE i_a.id IS NULL;
```

This gives me a list of id's that I have in `items_restored` that are not in `items_archive`, however the problem is that some of them MAY be present in `items`.  The same issue happens if I run the above query on `items` instead of `items_archive`, I see whats missing but it's very possible the missing id is in `items_archive`.

I need to run an `INSERT` eventually and I think if I do it piece meal based on these queries, there's a good chance I'm going to end up inserting duplicate records which I want to avoid.

How can I craft the query to check both `items` and `items_archive` id's to compare to my `items_restored` id's so that I can avoid the duplication?

Edit:  I ended up going with union all, which I did right after the `LEFT JOIN`.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: items UNION ALL items_archive?

Comment: Have you tried an approach like this? `SELECT ir.id
FROM items_restord ir
WHERE ir.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM items_archive)`

Comment: Comment as an answer I'll give it to you.  I don't know why I got so caught up in crafting a cool complicated query I forgot to simplify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ir.id  --, i_a.id -- this is always NULL so why select it?
FROM items_restord  ir LEFT JOIN
     items_archive i_a 
     ON ir.id = i_a.id LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON ir.id = i.id
WHERE i_a.id IS NULL AND i.id IS NULL;
```

I think `NOT EXISTS` is a cleaner way to express the logic:

```
select ir.*
from items_restord ir
where not exists (select 1 from items_archive i_a where ir.id = i_a.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from items i where ir.id = i.id);
```

Comment: I select the null because it gives me peace of mind to see there truly is no i_a.id, nothing more than that ha.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the merge statement.  You'll be able to compare all of the data between those, but set conditions based on matched, no match, etc.  which would alleviate some of the issues you denoted.  However, merge is only available in SQL Server 2008+ if I recall, so the syntax may not be available since you tagged only SQL.

```
MERGE INTO items_archive AS Target
USING (
     SELECT ...
     FROM items_restore AS Source (
          ...
     )
)

ON (target.Id = source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
     ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (
     ...
) VALUES ( 
     ...
)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

I did condense code for brevity since I am not sure of specific column names, but you can also couple with an output action to indicate what the query is doing easily.  But good way to merge data between tables of like sorts.

You mention finding the missing data, my thought was if a match does not exists it would be created and thrown into the output log.